# Wi-Fi still connected while MacBook in sleep mode

Tags: macos, mac, macbook, sleep, osx-yosemite

My brand new MacBook is still connected with Wi-Fi even after I put it in sleep mode. I discovered this when I pinged the MacBook's IP address from another machine accidentally.

Is this normal? Or a bug? Has anyone else noticed this problem?

Can anyone help by testing your own MacBook please?

I'm using a MacBook Pro 2015 running OS X v10.10.3, and yes I unchecked the Wake for Wi-Fi access and Power Nap options.

Comment: Do you have any AirPort base stations (Extremes, Expresses, or Time Capsules) or Apple TVs on the network? I wonder if it could be a Bonjour Sleep Proxy that's responding to your pings.

Comment: Have same situation, router still show conencted device, I try ping and it response until I disconnect macbook air from charger. After disconnect from charger macbook air disconnect from network and stop responding.

Comment: Can you share the output of `pmset -g` and `pmset -g log | grep -i "wake from" | head -10`? You didn't specifiy which sleep mode you are putting your laptop in and how.

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251397479

Answer (score 2):

**Yes,** This is normal and happens on my devices.
The network has to be alive at a low ticking over rate in case you try to open a Screen-Sharing session or any other Wake-on-LAN activities. If it dropped completely you would not be able to reach it from another device.
It is using a slow "heartbeat" to listen for certain activities directed at it. Just like the keyboard buttons have enough power to them to recognize if you touch them and wake up.
I hope that helps!

Comment: In this case, do I understand it correctly, that sending Wake-on-LAN magic packets is not required for Apple devices as they are waking up automatically when you try to access them in sleep mode?